# v-validate files.every is not a function

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vee-validate

i use bootstrap-vue and v-validate in vuejs, When I want to use validation in a input file, I get the following error:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in event handler for "input": "TypeError: files.every is not a function"
```

---

code:

```
<b-form-file
            id="attachment"
            name="attachment"
            accept="application/zip,image/x-png,image/jpeg"
            v-validate="'ext:zip,png,jpeg,jpg|size:10240'">
 </b-form-file>
```

[image: error code]

Comment: Not sure if this is right, you might've seen it, but I found this: https://github.com/baianat/vee-validate/issues/874